# how to make div in one box with side by side for currency input

Tags: html, css, flexbox

how to make box like above ? in pure css without boostrap [image: image here]

why i asked this because i don't use bootstrap 4 and can't find any way to use it with boostrap 3, i was trying to make one but it was the box become like a column down

here is my css:

```
.currency {
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  float:left;
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

and my htlm

```
<div>
  <label class="currency"></label>
  <input type="text"> 1000
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wrapper could be a `label` element, the currency sign can be the `::before` pseudoelement which can read a `data-*` attribute on the label itself.

```css
label {
   border: 2px #ccc solid;
   border-radius: .5em;
   display: inline-flex;
   color: #666;
   overflow: hidden;
   font: 2rem Verdana;
}

label:before {
   content: attr(data-currency);
   width: 2.5em;
   padding: .5em 0;
   background: #e6e6e8;
   text-align: center;
   font: inherit;
   border-right: inherit;
}

input {
   border: 0;
   padding: .25em .75em;
   font: inherit;
   color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<label aria-label="Enter the amount in €" data-currency="€">
   <input type="text" />
</label>
```

Comment: will it work when we dont use div and change to div or span

Comment: It will work. You can use any block label element and display set to `inline-flex` or `flex`.

Comment: i change input with span, and put text in it, but the text not in center

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

> this code is using bootstrap 3 so if you want then give a try